# How to setup apollo-angular in angular v16 or v17 to make it SSR (Server side rendered)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, apollo-angular, angular-ssr

In angular v16 or v17 the application configuration has the option/provider 'provideHttpClient(withFetch())'.

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, withInMemoryScrolling } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch, withInterceptorsFromDi, ɵwithHttpTransferCache } from '@angular/common/http';
import { graphqlProvider } from './graphql.provider';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes, withInMemoryScrolling({
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
  })), provideClientHydration(), provideHttpClient(
    withFetch(),
  ), graphqlProvider]
};
```

This works great with GET requests and every get request is unique. As the documentation says the HttpClient when used with fetch API.
But When it comes to graphql (I am using apollo-angular library), for every query and mutation the endpoint is same ( '/graphql' ) and request method is POST. So I finding hard time to understand and resolve this problem.

I tried adding this `ssrMode: true` in graphql provider code

```
import { Apollo, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';
import { ApplicationConfig, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ApolloClientOptions, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';

const uri = 'http://localhost:1337/graphql'; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function apolloOptionsFactory(): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  const httpLink = inject(HttpLink);
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    ssrMode: true
  };
}

export const graphqlProvider: ApplicationConfig['providers'] = [
  Apollo,
  {
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: apolloOptionsFactory,
  },
];
```

but that seems not enough and involves different methods I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`provideClientHydration()` accepts `withHttpTransferCacheOptions()` as argument where you can pass `includePostRequests: true`

So you need :

`provideClientHydration(withHttpTransferCacheOptions(includePostRequests: true))`

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to be working fine for me. Until hydration message pops up (which can take up to 15 seconds) search functionality doesn't work correctly in my app